# How do I fix this error message?

Tags: python, loops, subtraction

```
myVar = int(input("What do you want to start out with? "))
mySubtactor = int(input("What do you want to be the subtracter? "))


def function():
    choice = input("Do you want to take away? Please say yes or no. ")
    if(choice == 'yes'):
        print(myVar)
        myVar = myVar - mySubtactor
        function()
    if(choice == 'no'):
        print("You have decided not to subtract. Your number is still " + myVar)
        function()
function()
```

I keep on getting this error message:

> File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\new 3.py", line 8, in function print(myVar)
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myVar referenced before assignment

I'm sorry if this is a noob question but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def function():
  global myvar
  ...
```

You can use `myvar` without declaring `global`(just access `myvar` variable), but in your function you assigned it, so you need to use `global`.

**See also:**

- [The global statement](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=python%20%2b%20global%20variable&oq=python%20%2b%20global&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5239j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=141&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read up on scope and namespacing in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces.

Inside your `function()` you reference `myVar`. Python first looks in the local scope of `function()` before looking at the global scope. Since you assign to `myVar` in your function, the interpreter decides that this is a local variable, instead of using the global variable. But, as stated in the error message, you reference `myVar` before you assign to it.

If you don't assign to it in your function, then you can use a global variable without declaring it `global`:

```
myVar = 'hello'

def test():
    print myVar

test()
#hello
```

But if you assign to `myVar` in your function, then the local variable will be used:

```
myVar = 'hello'

def test():
    myVar = 'Goodbye'
    print myVar

test()
#Goodbye
print myVar
#hello
```

However, as you had, if you assign to `myVar` in your function, but refer to it before this, you will get an error:

```
myVar = 'hello'

def test():
    print myVar
    myVar = 'Goodbye'

test()
#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myVar' referenced before assignment
```

To solve the problem, you can declare your `myVar` global:

```
def function():
    global myVar
    ...
```

Or pass your variables to your function:

```
def function(myVar):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you need to pass myVar and mySubtractor to your function or call them globally or even set them up with the function